# Exclude JSON array fields for specifc values

Tags: json, linux, jq

Let's say I want to extract a `CSV` taking specific fields from a big `json` file generated from an `API`... everything of interest is inside an array.

```
jq -r ".array[] | [.uniqV,.V1,.V2,.V3] | @csv" something.json
```

... but if the unique value starts with a certain string (say, BAD-), I want to exclude the array member entirely.
I could do something like this...

```
jq -r ".array[] | [.uniqV,.v1,.v2,.v3] | @csv" something.json | egrep -v ^\"BAD-
```

... but it would be nicer / more efficient to exclude this pattern within `jq` itself. How could that be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Filter the records from `.array` before building the array fed to `@csv`.

```
jq -r '.array[] | 
         select(.uniqV | startswith("BAD-") | not) |
         [.uniqV, .v1, .v2, .v3] |
         @csv' something.json
```